# Can't get proper data from json file AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have problem with my first AngularJS app. I'm using yeoman generator. I need to get data from json file and check the length of array with objects.

**My data.json file:**

```
{"persons":[
    {  
         "firstname":"Christian",
         "lastname":"Bower",
         "age":21
      },
      {  
         "firstname":"Anthony",
         "lastname":"Martial",
         "age":25
      }
]}
```

**My angular controller:**

```
   'use strict';

        /**
         * @ngdoc function
         * @name webdevApp.controller:DataTableCtrl
         * @description
         * # DataTableCtrl
         * Controller of the webdevApp
         */
        angular.module('webdevApp')
          .controller('DataTableCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            this.awesomeThings = [
              'HTML5 Boilerplate',
              'AngularJS',
              'Karma'
            ];


            $http.get('../data.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.Data = data;
                $scope.namePerson = $scope.Data.persons[0].firstname;
            });

         console.log($scope.namePerson);
         console.log($scope.Data.length);
      });
```

**Console output:**

1) *undefined


2) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at new*

**Next question is - How can I achieve effect as below (array with objects)?**

```
$scope.persons = [
    { 
        "firstname": "christian", 
        "lastname": "bower", 
        "age": 21
    },
    { 
        "firstname": "anthony1", 
        "lastname": "martial", 
        "age": 25 
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get` is an asyncronous call so you have to output its results in the `success` function like this:

```
       $http.get('../data.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.Data = data;
            $scope.namePerson = $scope.Data.persons[0].firstname;

            console.log($scope.namePerson);
            console.log($scope.Data.length);

            $scope.persons = data.persons; // get your persons array
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to do all operations inside .success function ? How can I use my variables outside ? .hasOwnProperty method will be the simplest way to count my array items?

Comment: @XingD123, yes, whatever you do to your asynchronous call results - you do it in the `success` handler (meaning after the data is loaded). To get the number of array items use the `length` propery.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to do something like that $scope.getData = funcion () { $http.get().... } and later call my getData() function ? Is there another method to reach variables in whole script ?

Comment: Ok I have my answer. I'll use $.ajax() asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The `$http.get` call is **asynchronous**!

Put the logs in your `success` function.

```
$http.get('../data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.Data = data;
    $scope.namePerson = $scope.Data.persons[0].firstname;

    //assign persons in scope
    $scope.persons = data.persons;

    //logs
    console.log($scope.namePerson);
    console.log($scope.Data.length);
});
```

Note as a side remark that IMHO you should only assign `data` or even `persons`in scope since you can get everything from there. Putting thousands of useless variables in scope can create unwanted complexity.